# handling a well-formed JSON file of an array of objects

Tags: json, ruby

A JSON string string [passes the jsonlint test](https://jsonlint.com/).

```
response = [
  {
    "article" : {
      "info" : {
        "initial" : {
          "articleIds" : [
            "7461221587662919569"
          ],
        }
      },
      "text" : "where they would 'transfer to' next.",
      "lang" : "en",
    }
  },
  {
    "article" : {
      "info" : {
        "initial" : {
          "articleIds" : [
            "6613144915874808065"
          ],
        }
      },
      "text" : "produto regional.",
      "lang" : "pt"
    }
  }
]
```

However, after processing

```
require 'json'
file = File.read('/Users/main/jugg//article_samples.js')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

One is left with an array, whereas more frequently a hash with a name labels a subsequent array, where one works with that nomenclature such as `response['data']`

But in this case the array is not accessible via `response[0]`.  How can this be considered as an array in order to process each individual element `collection.each do |member|`?

*A curiosity: `data_hash.class => NilClass`*

Comment: If the input is as you say, then `data_hash` is an array, not a hash. So you can do `data_hash[0]`.

Comment: If that doesn't work, we will need more details. What do you mean by "But in this case the array is not accessible via response[0]". What happens when you do this? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, what is the value of `response[0]`?

Comment: `response[0]
> undefined local variable or method 'response' for main:Object (NameError)` whereas `data_hash[0]
> undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`  Where I had tried to inspect the class:  `data_hash.class > NilClass`

Comment: @Jerome You say "*A JSON string string passes the jsonlint test*" but then show a Ruby data structure. Can we see the actual JSON please? And is that the actual code you are running?

Comment: the question is amended.  the data is much greater, this being a smaller sample for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. If you add `response[0]` after `data_hash = ...`, then clearly it won't work because `response` isn't defined. I'm not sure about the second error. You will need to show the contents of `article_samples.js` before I can help you.

Comment: Is the `response = ...` code inside `article_samples.js`? If so, this is JavaScript code, not JSON data. So `JSON.parse()` won't work. In order to fix this, you need to create an actual JSON file with the data rather than trying to use a JavaScript file.

Comment: yes, that is correct.  So how should it be corrected?  I mean it is JavaScriptObjectNotation.  and the contnts passes the linter...  what am I misinterpreting here?

Comment: Is this file only used from your ruby code? Or is it also used from some JavaScript code?

Comment: only used for ruby code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response = ...` code from `article_samples.js` is JavaScript, not JSON. This initializes a variable named `response` with a JavaScript array.

To use this as JSON, then rename the file to `article_samples.json` and remove `response =`  from the file. The first line should start with `[`.

Now your second block of code should work just fine as long as the `article_samples.json` file is in the correct path.

On a side note, I suggest that you find a way to make the path more flexible. The way you have it currently hard coded is tied directly to your current machine's file system. This won't work if you want to run this code from another machine because the folder `/Users/main/jugg` probalby won't exist.

If this is a web server with ruby on rails, then one solution is to create an environment variable with the path where this file is stored.

Comment: Oh it will be.  Just right now it is small incremental steps.  Then, how is the collection invoked, in order to then process each individual article?

Comment: @Jerome Terminology: you can *index* an array or or collection, but not invoke one. Instead you invoke functions and methods. Once you parse the JSON array, you will have an array in ruby that you can process in the same way you do any array. To get a single item you can index with `data[0]` (I assume you use a variable named `data` rather than `data_hash`.) To process every element, you will need a loop of some sort. I would suggest using the `map()` or `each()` functions on the array.